# guzzle xml request returns only plain text

Tags: php, xml, laravel, request, guzzle

im trying to make a xml request to a ws using guzzle,(and i try with curl to) in php but always the response its in plain text no in xml

```
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]);

        $soapRequest  = <<<XML
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:san="mywebsservice">                  
                <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                    <wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/mywebsservice</wsa:Action>                   
                        <To soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">mywebsservice </To>                    
                </soap:Header>                  
                <soap:Body>                 
                    <tem:GetSecurityToken>                  
                        <tem:request>                   
                            <san:Connection>mywebsservice</san:Connection>                  
                            <san:Passwoord>mywebsservice</san:Passwoord>                    
                            <san:System>mywebsservice</san:System>                  
                            <san:UserName>mywebsservice</san:UserName>                  
                        </tem:request>                  
                    </tem:GetSecurityToken>                 
                </soap:Body>                    
        </soap:Envelope>
XML;
        $request = $client->request('POST','mywebsservice', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml'
            ],
            'body' => $soapRequest                         
        ]);
        $response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    var_dump($response);
```

this is the response 
 this is the response

```
string(1870) "
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/webservices/GetSecurityTokenResponse</a:Action>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="cf1c12da-af1b-4013-ba89-25db2fa67dc1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetSecurityTokenResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetSecurityTokenResult xmlns:b="webservices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <b:AccessToken>token access</b:AccessToken>
                <b:IdToken>the token</b:IdToken>
                <b:TokenType>Bearer</b:TokenType>
            </GetSecurityTokenResult>
        </GetSecurityTokenResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

"

Comment: i wanna get a xml response and not a plain text

Comment: Maybe you need to add a `Accept` header to to your request. What the `Accept` header does is getting explained here --> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31231

Comment: What do you think XML is other than text? Post what you are getting and what you are expecting instead, and why

Comment: i try with 'Accept'     => 'application/json', and 'Accept'     => 'application/soap+xml', and i got the same result

Comment: i need to parse that request to a json or an array and when i use something like this
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), false);
only returns to me if i encode to an array returns empty array and if i encode to a object returns a empty object

Comment: Have you ever tried `simplexml_load_string($response)`?

Comment: I try with simple load string but when I pass before through Jason encode returns me an empty object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers you are sending is what the receiving server uses to decide what content to serve. It will still be text content though, but only with a different `Content-Type` header.

#### `guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.x`

The `$response->json()` and `$response->xml()` helpers were removed in 6.x. The following lines can be used to replicate that behaviour:

```php
// Get an associative array from a JSON response.
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```php
// Get a `SimpleXMLElement` object from an XML response.
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response->getBody());
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

#### `guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.x`

Guzzle 5.x has some shortcuts to help you out:

```php
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com']);

$response = $client->get('/');
// $response = Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface

$body = (string) $response->getBody();
// $body = raw request contents in string format.
// If you dont cast `(string)`, you'll get a Stream object which is another story.
```

Now whatever you do with `$body` is up to you. If it is a JSON response, you'd do:

```php
$data = $response->json();
```

If it is XML, you can call:

```php
$xml = $response->xml();
```

I never work with XML APIs so i can't give you any more examples on how to traverse the XML you will retrieve.

Comment: Thanks I gone try and I let you know about the resukt. Thanks

Comment: i try, but its not a method for guzzle 6,  and i try with curl and i have the same error the response its plain text

Comment: i've updated the answer, i wasnt aware that they were removed.

Comment: perfect now i gone try with the 
// Get an associative array from a JSON response.
$data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

Comment: with the 6.x returns a NULL value

Comment: and if i try with the simplexml load string returns me 
object(SimpleXMLElement)#427 (0) {
}

Comment: so it works. Depending on what you have to do you have to work with that XML object

Comment: It works but I can't see anything inside the object, I supposed it was going to give me the answer that was in plain text on an object

Comment: Yes it is a pain to work with. Try out `$xml->children('s', true)->Body->children()->children()->children('b', true)[1]` to get the value of `b:idToken`. It is pretty difficult to traverse these trees. You can debug it with the `asXML()` function like `$xml->children('s', true)->asXML()`. But sadly print_r/var_dump dont do much.

Comment: Thanks mate when arrive to my home in a hour I test and I let you know the result

Comment: i try it but i have this error function children() on string , and i try to put like this 
$xml = $request->getBody()->getContents();
        
        if(false !== $xml){
         $data=$xml->children('s', true)->Body->children()->children()->children('b', true)[1];
         return $data;
   }
but sitll have the same error

Comment: reaqlly thanks i solved with you last comment i didnt solved on guzzle buts works on curl

Comment: Guzzle works with the curl handler as well though so it can be solved with both.